# Got 419 error occasionally in laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, csrf

I got 419 (Sorry, your session has expired. Please refresh and try again.) **occasionally** in different browsers when login my system.

**Browsers**

- Chrome (worked)
- Firefox (worked)
- Safair (419)
- IE10 (419)

I have tried these but still **doesn’t** work.

- Use different laravel version (5.7.6, 5.7.9, 5.7.22, ...).
- Regenerate app keys.
- Try `{{ csrf_field() }}`, `@csrf` in form.
- Add `SESSION_DOMAIN=xxx` to .env file
- Clear all browser caches.

At last, I turned off the csrf verification. The 419 gone, but the login is also failed with 302 error.I don't what happened, can anyone help me?

Comment: does your laravel app uses load balancer or some sort of CDN ?

Comment: Regenerating app keys or clearing browser caches might actually make the problem worse instead of better. this problem usually occurs when session data that is expected to remain is flushed or the session cookie disappears. It might be worthwhile trying to figure out if there's more specific steps to reproduce this. Also 302 is not an error but a redirect response.

Comment: Do you have a session timeout of 0? Are your cookies secure or http only? Do you have some kind of custom Middleware to ensure a access?

Comment: No load balance, no CDN, no custom middleware, http only is true, The problem is that it happens occasionally in different browsers.

Answer (score -1):

Add @csrf code on the button to solve it :)

Comment: OP said that he tried putting `@csrf` in form and id DOES NOT work. Read questions carefully before answering, especially when they are 1 year old.